# Track step by step performance / execution time

Tags: 6

Drupal 6 site is slow.

Want to track performance / page execution time.
- check each step, PHP code, execution time
- check JavaScript execution time
- check CSS execution time

Krumo prints out the function stack, each step/function from bootstrap to the page up.
Could Krumo give information about the execution time of each step?

There are also other tools, such as the following listing:

drupa.org project performance

Performance Logging and Monitoring

drupal.org project xhprof

XHProf

drupal.org project profiling

Profiling

What are the tools / methods to track the step by step performance (execution time)?